# how to Invoke directive function from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

JavaScript function:

```
 var API = (function(){
        return {
            function invokeDirective(){
                invvoke();
                $scope.setItem() // to directive
            }       
        }
    });
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('sampleComponents', ['$strap.directives']).directive('titlebar',
function($filter,$timeout)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="searchBar r  etc ........',
        controller: function($scope,$http,$timeout)
        {
            $scope.setItem = function(){
                // want to invoke this function from api.js -
            }
        }
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // etc:
        }

});
```

how can I invoke `$scope.setItem` from `api.js`? Is it possible? Please suggest.

(currently, I am using timer, but that is creating some performance issue )

Comment: API.js should itself be an Angular service, injected into your directive as a dependency. You should then expose the service's calls via an external API if required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with a very hacky way.

Demo code:

```
//This is too get scope outside of angular controller/service/directive
//with a hacky way to do that.

var $injector =angular.injector(['ng','MyApp']);
var html = "<div titlebar=''></div>";
$injector.invoke(function($compile, $rootScope){
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var result= $compile(html)($scope);

    var cScope = result.scope(); // This is scope in directive controller. :  )
    //Do anything you want with this scope .
});
```

[This is Jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/srdbsznL/4/)

Happy coding. : )